# Displaying Json data in Aframe text box

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to display json text to aframe text box? My code is shared below. I am a beginner to Aframe.

```
<script src="webar.json">
function myfunction()
{
 var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
 var data=mydata[0].city;
 return data;
}
AFRAME.registerComponent('displayjson', {
init: function(){
var m=myfunction();
this.el.setAttribute('value', m);
}
});
</script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>
<a-marker preset="hiro">
<a-text displayjson position='-.5 -1 -1.2' rotation='-45 0 0' color='red'></a-text>
<a-entity position='-.5 -1 -.9' rotation='-45 0 0' color='red' text="value: Hello"></a-entity>
</a-marker>
<a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not updating the component correctly:

`this.el.setAttribute('text', {value: "YOUR TEST"});`

[Docs clarify](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute)